# How to deserilize properly when posting Json to ASP.NET MVC Actions where the model has Subclasses

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem where when sending JSON to some action on an MVC controller, that Action accepts a model where there is a list of items.   Those items can be several different objects  as they are all subclasses of a common abstract class.

Is there a way to craft the JSON so that when it deserilizes it, it knows how to convert the objects back into the correct types?

Comment: If you are not using JSON.NET then you should, you can specify subclassing parsing using annotations or configuration.

Comment: so with json.net how do you hook it in as a value provider and getting it to handle deserializing subclassed objects?

Answer (score 0):

```
    void Main()
{
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
 MainModel model = new MainModel(){SimpleProperty = "I am simple property",   ComplexProperty = new ComplexProperty(){Foo="test", Bar="data"}};
   var result = serializer.Serialize(model);
```

}

```
public class MainModel
  {
      public string SimpleProperty {get;set;}
      public ComplexProperty ComplexProperty {get;set;}
}

 public class ComplexProperty 
  {
public string Bar {get;set;}
public string Foo {get;set;}

  }
```

The result of the serialization looks like this : 
{"SimpleProperty":"I am simple property","ComplexProperty":{"Bar":"data","Foo":"test"}}

Hope that helps!

Comment: Forgot to mention that var query = serializer.Deserialize<MainModel>(result);

Comment: Oh i thought it was asking how to deserialize it to its correct original type which i missed out in my original answer but later posted in the comments.Is that what you were looking for ?

Comment: no, what was needed was a way a way to have an object graph that could deserialize json with subclasses....   eg,  if your example you had a base class Complex, your ComplexProperty inherited off it, and there was another class called EvenMoreComplex that inherits it too, then in MainModel you have a reference to Complex, which could be any of the three types.   In Json.Net there is the ability to serialize type information into json so when you deserialize it, it will recreate the correct type of object